# Translating a rest API call from angular to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, rest

Apologies if worded awkwardly, but I have to make an rest API call using jQuery. I've already made the call using angularJS before, but for this case I can't use that. I tried translating it to jQuery but I'm not getting the same results. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or am I missing information? I'm fairly new to jQuery so I feel as if I'm missing something crucial or misunderstood something.

Working code with angularJS:

```
var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://fakeurl.com/rest/v1/portal/user/' + $scope.email.value,
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Header_1': 'Yes',
            'x-access-token': 'glsFromWebsite' //$scope.authInfo.token
        }
    };

    restCall($http, req).then(function (res) {

        // check for error even though 200 response
        if (res.error) {
            console.error("Error reported...");    
        } else {
`         //enter success code here
        }
    });

var restCall = function(http, req) {
  var _url = getBaseUrl() + req.url;
  req.url = _url;

  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    try {

      http(req).then(function (res) {

        // check for error even though 200 response
        if (res.data.error) {
          if (res.data.error === '601') {
            console.error('Token is invalid or has expired');
          } else {
            console.error("Error from end point: " + res.data.error);
          }
        } 
        fulfill(res.data);

      }, function(err) {
        console.error('Error calling rest endpoint',err);
        reject();
      });  

    } catch (ex) {
      console.error('Exception calling rest endpoint',ex);
      reject(ex);
    }
  }); 
};
```

My failing jQuery code:

```
var processCreate = function (email) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://fakeurl.com/rest/v1/portal/user/' + email.value,
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Header_1': 'Yes',
            'x-access-token': 'glsFromWebsite' //$scope.authInfo.token
        },
        success: function (res, a, b) {
            if (res === 'NOT FOUND') {
                //code that runs when this case is true
            } else {
                //code that runs when this case is false
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.error("Error...");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try using jquery? Like a 404, or a 500?

Comment: By "Failing" whats the console log error look like, that's where the debugging starts

Comment: @KreepN I don't get any error in the console when attempting to use jQuery. I'm pretty certain that I have all the jQuery libs necessary to run the code.

Comment: Well you'd probably see the call being made in your net panel of whatever browser you are using. If you see it, it should tell you the response code. If you do not see it in the network tab, it means the call isn't even being made.

Comment: @FrickeFresh I don't get any errors. The purpose of the code is to make a form in a php file to submit if successful (the res === 'NOT FOUND') part, if not, the form does not submit and a modal is show. However, every time I run it, it refreshes the page, making me think that it is trying to submit.

Comment: @FrickeFresh it's also possible that the issue might lie with the php file I have, but I want to be sure. Judging by the jQuery code I have, does it look like it should run? Or is there something wrong there?

Comment: The jquery looks fine, but if you're submitting this via ajax I'm not sure why your page would be refreshing.

Comment: @Juan I think you should remove whatever that is reloading the page so you can see the logs, also remove the if statements in success function. success and error function should look like this 
`success: function (res, a, b) {
           console.log(res);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making an ajax call like this

```
var processCreate = function (email) {           
                var authHeaders = {};
                authHeaders.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + 'glsFromWebsite';

               $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://fakeurl.com/rest/v1/portal/user/' + email.value,
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType : "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    headers: authHeaders,
                    success: function (data) {

                        //console.log(data);
                        if (data === 'NOT FOUND') {
                          //code that runs when this case is true
                        } else {
                          //code that runs when this case is false
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't seem to work. I try to debug from Chrome, but it doesn't run neither the success nor the error functions. I put breakpoints in within Ajax, but it skips over them.

Comment: Is url made after it is the correct one? I guess their might be some issue with url. Is email.value have some value in it ?

Comment: In your original code you call getBaseUrl() and add it to _req.url so ajax url should be somewhat similar to it. But in ajax we don't append getBaseUrl(). Please check if that might be an issue. Thanks

Comment: That isn't the problem. I changed the original code when I pasted it on here to avoid any confusion, but I forgot to remove the baseURL. After testing some more, I realized that my code actually does make the correct API call. The issue now seems to be that the page unexpectedly refreshes before I can see any results. Likely completely unrelated to anything I posted. I do appreciate the answer, though.